# How to generate 504 gateway timeout error

Tags: http-status-code-504

I am testing a web application, which was sometimes generating 504, gateway timeout error. I want to check whether it is still generating the same or not.Is there any way by which I can generate the 504 error again?

Answer (score 1):

Try after blocking using the firewall service or by disconnecting the server. 
You may refer more here : https://www.keycdn.com/support/504-gateway-timeout/